# ruby で `obj.(arg)` の記法は一体何ですか？

Tags: ruby

https://github.com/trailblazer/cells

上記 gem の README を読んでいたところ、以下のような example code がありました。

```
CommentCell.(@comment).()
```

## 質問

1. これは一体どのような ruby コードなのでしょうか？
2. 名前なしメソッドというのが ruby にはある、のでしょうか？
3. 自分でこのような挙動をするクラスを実装する場合には、どのように記述したら良いのでしょうか？

Comment: [... The foo.(bar) syntax is just syntactic sugar for foo.call(bar). ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4294660)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `CommentCell.call(@comment).call()` と同じ動作をするコードです
2. ないです。名前なしで `.()` と書くと `call` メソッドが呼び出されます。
3. `call` メソッドを実装すると `.()` で呼び出せるようになります。

```rb
class C
  def call
    puts :call
  end
end

C.new.()
# call
```